# Unable to send back data to action in MVC controller from javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I use jquery to load rows into a table. Each row contains an Id.

```
row = '<tr><td><button type="button" class="edit-form btn btn-default" data-form-id="' + value[0].id + '"></button></td></tr>';
tbody.append(row);
```

On click of a button, I need this Id to be sent back to an action in the controller, which would then redirect to a new view with this Id. On the new page, I would use this Id in a javascript function, which would then load details pertaining to this id using jQuery ajax.
I am not able to acheive this. I tried several things

- Tried creating html action link using javascript which did not work
- Used ajax to send data(id) to the action, but the action ended up returning the html of the new view as the response instead of redirecting

I've gone through several other Stackoverflow question related to this and have tried all of them. Nothing seems to work. Please suggest how i should tackle this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have sent data to other actions in the controller, but now my problem is that, I need this Id to go to the action and it should redirect me to a new page with this info available on that page

I have pasted the Code Below for the things I have tried.

```
$.each(this.data, function (key, value) {
            var row = '<button type="button" class="edit-form btn btn-default" data-form-id="' + value[0].id + '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td></tr>';
            tbody.append(row);
        });
```

On click of this button I call the following code in my javascript

```
openEditForm: function (evt) {
        var formId = $(evt.currentTarget).data("formId");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Test',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ formId: formId }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            success: function (response) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

In my Controller I have an action named Test which does the following

```
public ActionResult Test(string formId)
    {            
        ViewBag.Title = "Testing Page ";
        ViewBag.Message = "Testing Page" + formId + "hi";            
        return View();
    }
```

What I want is that the action receive this formId and redirect it to a view called Test.cshtml. I need that view to have the formId info in it, so that I can use javascript on that page to make ajax calls to retreive the form info.

Comment: Your post is rather vague.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish and if you could post more code (say, your code behind). That would help.  My best guess at the moment is that you're rendering a row in a table and jQuery has not been bound to that button.

Comment: Please Some more Codes ...Because what you have tried matters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Used ajax to send data(id) to the action, but the action ended up returning the html of     
the new view as the response instead of redirecting
```

By Above Line You Mean to Say that You want Data to Be posted to action ,and Action1 will call another Action where it will use That Returned ID...

So if this is The Case then Why are You using Ajax?

```
function myfunction()
{
  var formId = $(evt.currentTarget).data("formId");

  // window.location = "ActionNameHere?formId" + formId;
 // foryour Case
 window.location="Test?formId="+formId;

}
```

The Above code will Redirect you to

```
public ActionResult Test(string formId)
{            
    ViewBag.Title = "Testing Page ";
    ViewBag.Message = "Testing Page" + formId + "hi";            
    return View();
}
```

From here you will have your New Page with Id in it...
The best way to initiate an HTTP request is with

```
  document.loacation.href.replace('URL')
```

Comment: That did it.. I was complicating it with an ajax call which was totally not required. So if the javascript in the new page needs to access this, is it enough for me to assign this formId to a hidden input and then use javascript on page load to check its value? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Actually you can do 2 things... If data is this only you can use as Viewbag in the page... But if Your data  is Big and you want to use it mannerly use strongly typed Model

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

option a) create a form element with an hidden field, populate it when the user clicks on the button and then submit the form to your action

```
<form method="post" action="/yourController/yourAction" id="frmAction">
  <input type="hidden" name="parameterYouExpectinYourAction" value="" id="hdnField" />
</form>
<script>
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  $("#hdnField").val($(this).data("form-id"));
  $("#frmAction").submit();
});
</script>
```

option b) create a normal link instead of a button like

```
'<a href="/controller/youraction?yourParam=' + value[0].id + '" >link</a>'
```

Is not the cleanest way, but could help you to make it work of figure out how to get it done in other ways (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see is simply an event on your button with a redirect to the URL with the ID.

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    window.location = 'http://yourURL' + '/' + $(this).attr('data-form-id');
});
```

Just modify it following your needs of course (`Html.Action(...)`, `$.post(...)`, ...).

Once inside your controller you can use `return RedirectToAction(...)` combined with the ID submitted to redirect the user to your second view.